# python array sklearn StandardScaler returns all zeros

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, scale

I have problem with standardizing data
everything returns zeros.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

data = np.array([[11.2, 18.5, 78.3, 451.00, 0.092, 0.081, 0.031, 0.042, 0.19, 0.062,
                      0.33, 1.37, 2.33, 27.2, 0.0075, 0.016, 0.015, 0.010, 0.012, 0.0031,
                      14.8, 28.6, 92.3, 632.1, 0.17, 0.32, 0.26, 0.21, 0.38, 0.0943]])
std = StandardScaler()
std.fit(data)
data_std = std.transform(data)
print(data_std)
```

and result is

```
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

expectation of result is

```
[[-0.81040387 -0.20004863 -0.54257553 -0.55723686 -0.35369336 -0.45358275
  -0.7203131  -0.18436828  0.29230371 -0.15060502 -0.25696325  0.31089387
  -0.25053599 -0.27024164  0.21836384 -0.52674695 -0.54547784 -0.30526892
  -1.03329333 -0.26720427 -0.29416565  0.44484725 -0.43381103 -0.4236021
   1.64341685  0.37871516 -0.09310786  1.3929505   1.38677111  0.53231628]]
```

Comment: The result with all zeros is correct. The reason why you're getting all zeros in the standardized output is because you're only passing a single data point to the StandardScaler and it calculates the mean and standard deviation for the single data point, and since the mean is equal to the data point itself, the result after scaling will be zero. Try passing multiple inputs to get the expected output.

Comment: Refer this: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html

Comment: thx!!!! solved it by using the same transformer that I fitted with the training data Thank you!